# What is best practice to add list item in SharePoint 2013 javascript object model?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

I need reference code to add an item to a list programmaticaly via javascript object model in SharePoint 2013.. Got many solutions online but not sure what js to include, whether ajax calls are need as given in [this msdn article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Basically the javascript will be put into an application page and every time the page is opened/refreshed a new item with logged in username should get inserted into the list.

Thanks.

Comment: You are referring the right article .You do not need any ajax calls. Refer this Section:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201%28v=office.15%29.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemCRUD of the same article.

Comment: I cannot use the section code mentioned without importing some js files right..? Dont I have to add reference to some js or ajax file?

Comment: Yes make sure this code is run after 'SP.js' is loaded. You can call your method to create list item like this SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', createListItem);. See this link for more info about this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: what about: ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded?

Comment: I want a article that has this simple code. Sadly there are none that I found.

Comment: Are you creating a SharePoint 2013 app?

Comment: ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded will only wait untill the script is loaded and then executes the function, but if that js is not referenced it will never execute.But SP.SOD.executeFunc will load the js if not already loaded and then execute. So SP.SOD.executeFunc will make sure the script is loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refer this [Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201%28v=office.15%29.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemCRUD) to add/update/Delete list items using javascript.

Make sure 'SP.js' is loaded before you call your method to add list item.You can do that as below:

```
  SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', createListItem);//makes sure sp.js is loaded and then calls createListItem method
    function createListItem() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();//if the page and the list are in same site.If list is in different site then use relative url instead of get_current
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');

        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
        oListItem.set_item('Body', 'Hello World!');
        oListItem.update();

        clientContext.load(oListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

SharePoint CSOM `List` client object exposes [List.AddItem method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.additem%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to create a new list item in the list:

```
public ListItem AddItem(
    ListItemCreationInformation parameters
)
```

Since `CSOM` is asynchronous, two approaches are commonly used when it comes to make CSOM code **maintainable**:

- Callbacks
- Deferred

### Callback approach

```
function AddListItem(listTitle,itemProps,OnItemAdded,OnItemError)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();

    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    for(var propName in itemProps) {
       listItem.set_item(propName, itemProps[propName]) 
    }

    listItem.update();
    context.load(listItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          OnItemAdded(listItem);           
        },
        OnItemError
    );
}
```

Usage

```
AddListItem('Contacts',contactEntry,
         function(contactItem){
            console.log('Contact ' + contactItem.get_item('Title') + ' has been created successfully');
         },
         function(sender,args){
            console.log('Error occured while creating contact:' + args.get_message());
});
```

### Deferred approach

> A deferred - is a pattern that returns an object immediately from an
>   asynchronous call

```
function AddListItemD(listTitle,itemProps)
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();

        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

        for(var propName in itemProps) {
           listItem.set_item(propName, itemProps[propName]) 
        }

        listItem.update();
        context.load(listItem);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
               dfd.resolve(listItem);
            },
            function (sender, args) {
               dfd.reject(args.get_message());
            }
        );
    });
    return dfd.promise();    
}
```

Usage

```
AddListItemD('Contacts',contactEntry).then(function(contactItem){
    console.log('Contact ' + contactItem.get_item('Title') + ' has been created successfully');
});
```

---

Since `SP.SOD.executeFunc` supports on demand scripts, but `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` does not, I would recommend to use `SP.SOD.executeFunc` with CSOM in application pages:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

please see my post here, it will tell you how to add a SP.List item with all available column types by using JSOM

http://pointofint.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-set-any-spfield-value-with-jsom.html

Comment: Add details to your post instead of linking to your own blog. If your blog goes down your answer will not be helpful at all to future readers