# How can I create a new list item in SharePoint with attachments without using jQuery

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to create a SharePoint list item from a HTML file loaded into a SharePoint page.

The issue that I am facing is that the business will not allow any external CDN's meaning that any `.js` code has to be written and cannot link to jQuery files.

Does anyone have any points for how to create a SP list items with attachments without using jQuery / .ajax etc.?

I am have managed to get xmlhttpRequest to work to pull the information  but cannot find a push / post solution.

Comment: Downloading jQuery files --> Uploading it to SharePoint document library (probably "Site Assets") --> And referencing the files from SharePoint. Is this approach allowed by your business?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? You can also use **JSOM** for CRUD operations.

Comment: downloads are not allowed either so I am not able to download the files. We are using SharePoint 2013 on premise. JSOM should would though. Do you have any useful resources you could advise of please for item creation with attachments?

Comment: Sure, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not able to use jQuery/.ajax, you can also use **JSOM** for CRUD operations.

Follow below link for creating list items & adding attachments:

**To create a new list item**:

1. [How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items Using JavaScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185011(v=office.14))
2. [What is best practice to add list item in SharePoint 2013 javascript object model?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93699/what-is-best-practice-to-add-list-item-in-sharepoint-2013-javascript-object-mode)

**To add list attachments**:

1. [Upload File To List Item In Office 365 As An Attachment Using JavaScript Object Model](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-file-to-listitem-in-office-365-as-an-attachment-using-javascript-object-m/)